# How to convert maven project to web application project?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, m2eclipse, vs-web-application-project

I want to convert a maven project to a web application project, which should contain web.xml. I am using eclipse juno 4.2 with m2e (maven integration for eclipse) plugin software.

Any reply would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

- Install [m2e-wtp](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/download/)
- In your pom.xml, change or add the *war* packaging
- right-click on project > Maven > Update project
- m2e-wtp will create the src/main/webapp folder and add the Dynamic Web project Facet¤
- manually add a WEB-INF folder under src/main/webapp
- right-click on project > Java EE Tools > Generate Deployment Descriptor stub
  It will create a web.xml under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/

¤ By default, the web facet is set to 2.5. You should update it, if needed, under project properties > Project Facets BEFORE generating the web.xml

Answer (score 2):

I assume your current project is a maven project which produces jar. Please confirm.

I have not come across any utility which can convert a jar project to a war project.

You have following two options -

1. Simple open the pom.xml and change jar to war. Create folder webapp under src/main and create a web.xml
2. Create a new web app project via maven command line choosing webapp archetype or via eclipse choosing maven webapp achetype. Define dependency to your jar project.

If you can provide more information based on my suggestion then probably I can help.