# jersey - ClassNotFoundException org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, servlets

When I deploy my rest api with jersey to a tomcat 7.0 server I get an error that has been discussed on stackoverflow quite often but I haven't been able to resolve it:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:495)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:477)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5362)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Things I have checked:

***Avoiding duplicate jersey versions***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So, `ServletContainer` is definitely imported

[image: ServletContainer.class in Maven dependencies]

I notice however in the dependency hierarchy that the jersey servlet container is also imported through another library (`dropwizard-core -> dropwizard-jersey -> jersey-container-servlet: 2.16`) and the versions differ (my version is `2.25.1`). But it says `omitted for conflict with 2.25.1`

[image: jersey servlet container of different version also imported by different lib]

***Where is Apache Tomcat v7.0 package library***

My project was originally a pure Maven project and I added the `Dynamic Web Project` facet lateron. When I compare to a test project where I successfully tested a jersey rest api, I don't see the `Apache Tomcat v7.0` libraries on my build path. In my test project I see

[image: build path of successful rest api project]

versus

[image: build path of actual project]

***WebContent/WEB-INF/lib is empty***

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444790/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer) the jersey libraries should be deployed to my `WEB-INF/lib/` folder. I did `Project -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies -> Finish`. But as soon as I do `Project -> Maven -> Update` the step above is reset (i.e. I don't see `Maven Dependencies` in the `Web Deployment Assembly` anymore. Despite this is strange, in the successful test jersey project the `lib` folder is also empty.

**EDIT**

There is something more fundamental going wrong. In the successful jersey rest api, I got the subfolder structure

- target
  +---- generated-sources
  +---- JerseyRestDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +---- m2e-wtp
  +---------- web-resources
  +----------------- META-INF
  +-----------------------maven
  +---- maven-archiver
  +--------- pom.properties
  +---- test-classes
- WebContent
  +---- META-INF
  +--------- MANIFEST.MF
  +---- WEB-INF
  +--------- lib
  +----------web.xml

However, in my current project I just see

- target
  +----- generated-sources
  +---------- annotations
  +----- maven-status
  +---------- maven-compiler-plugin
  +--------------- compile
- WebContent
  +---- META-INF
  +--------- MANIFEST.MF
  +---- WEB-INF
  +--------- lib
  +----------web.xml

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I converted the project again from maven to webapp following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101839/how-to-convert-maven-project-to-web-application-project) and then it worked